# JSP does not show any values that is set in req object in servlet

Tags: adobe, aem

From one JSP through hyperlink im calling another JSP (/content/nextgen/marine/viewpod.html) . Internally in that JSP (viewport.html) I'm calling servlet using ( ) , servlet page also called and I'm doing some logic and set some values in request.setAttribute and pass to JSP(/content/nextgen/marine/viewpod.html) page using forward method. Page is also retuned but no data is showing.

Comment: if your jsp session has been enabled. try setting it via `request.getSession().setAttribute("key", value);` and get back using `request.getSession().removeAttribute("key");` once your requirement is done you need to remove it with `request.getSession().removeAttribute("key");` the another way is passing the required variables in hidden field as `<input name="yourkeyname" type="hidden" value=""/>`

Comment: No jsp session im using it. In Jsp1 Page Im using as <a href="/content/nextgen/marine/viewpod.html " ></a>, it will land in JSP2 where i'll call servlet using <jsp:include page="/bin/servlet/viewpod"> and set some values in list (uploadedfiledetails.add(pod);) then into req obj (request.setAttribute("uploadedfiledetails", uploadedfiledetails);) the im trying to forward it using

Comment: request.getRequestDispatcher(redirect).forward(request, response);

Comment: ERROR:28.02.2017 13:02:12.850 *ERROR* [127.0.0.1 [1488267100641] GET /content/nextgen/marine/viewpodupload.html HTTP/1.1] org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl service: Uncaught SlingException
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Response already committed
 at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.SlingRequestDispatcher.forward(SlingRequestDispatcher.java:125)